# I am trying to open a https site , using curl in php . But I am getting a blank page

Tags: php, curl

I am trying to open a https site , using curl in php . But I am getting a blank page .Though when i checked I can find that the httpcode returned is 200. I am able to open the same page using the browser . I have disbaled the ssl verifyer and ssl_verify host since the host name and the name in the certifcate was different .

Here is my code any help would be useful

```
<?php
$url = "https://abcde.com/";
$ch = curl_init($url);
echo "init";
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 200);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD,"uname:pwd");
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST,1);
$curl_scraped_page= curl_exec($ch);
$httpCode=curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE); 
if(!$curl_scraped_page)
{
    echo "first learn";
}
echo $httpCode ;
echo $curl_scraped_page;
curl_close($ch);
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try using CURLOPT_USERAGENT  to set the user agent to the same one your browser uses.  They may be using user agent sniffing.

Comment: HI , Thanks but could you please help me how can I get the user agent parameter of my current browser , I am using Safari on MAC OSx.

Comment: HI , Could you also help me since , i am able to open a site with the same browser so how can user agnet sniffing be a factor .

Comment: http://whatsmyuseragent.com/ .  Take that value and use it to set CURLOPT_USERAGENT .

Answer (score 0):

Set this option:

```
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
```